# Problem with converting docker command to compose file

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose

I am trying to run my flask app in 2 ways: by use docker run command and by use a compose file. When i use following commands everything is working fine:

> docker container run --name flask-database -d --network flask_network
> -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin -e POSTGRES_DB=flask_db -v postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p
> 5432:5432 postgres:13
>
> docker container run -p 5000:5000 --network flask_network flask_app

But when I am trying to use my compose file (by docker compose up) i see error:

```
 File "/app/main_python_files/routes.py", line 11, in home
web               |     cur.execute('SELECT * FROM books;')
web               | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "books" does not exist
web               | LINE 1: SELECT * FROM books;
```

When i have to change in my compose file? I will be very grateful for response! Here is my compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  flask-database:
    container_name: flask-database
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - flask_network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=flask_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    container_name: web
    #build: web
    image: flask_app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - flask_network
    depends_on:
      - flask-database
    links:
      - flask-database
networks:
  flask_network: {}
volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
```

Comment: What should run an SQL `CREATE TABLE` command in this setup?

Comment: (Compose [automatically creates a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and you can safely remove all of the `networks:` blocks.  You also don't need to specify `container_name:`.  `links:` activates an obsolete networking mode and you should definitely remove it; Docker named networks replace its functionality.)

Comment: `flask-database` does not have the database files loaded at startup. Instead of building from `postgres:13` image, you need to create a dockerfile, which does a `COPY` of the volume(which has the db). You still need to mount the volume for the the db changes to persist.

Comment: But why everything is working when I am using docke4r command with postgres:13 image?